# Accessing CheckBoxMultiple selected items in Django Template

Tags: jquery, html, django, forms

I'm trying to replace a CheckBoxSelectMultiple field with an autocompleting drop-down menu. When an autocompleted item is selected, a hidden input is appended to a div with the value of the item selected, so it looks the same as a checkbox field once the form has been submitted.

The problem, however, is restoring these list items when there are errors in the form. Ideally, I could create a custom widget that would inherit from the CheckBoxSelectMultiple widget, but there doesn't seem to be any documentation on how to do this. Instead, I figured I could resort to something resembling the following:

```
{% for box in checkboxes.selected %}
<li>
<span class="selectedItem">
    {{ box.field1 }} ({{box.field2}})
    <input type="hidden" value="{{box.id}}" name="selectedItems"/>
</span>
</li>

{% endfor %}
```

This is a pretty hacky solution to a problem that must be fairly common. I imagine there's a fairly elegant way to solve this that I'm not seeing here. **I should add that** this is going to be going within a formset as well, so if I'm modifying the view I'd need to capture the prefix for each form in the formset, hence why I'm avoiding doing so.

Comment: Have you considered using [django-autocomplete-light](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/stable-2.x.x/) it does pretty much everything you are asking?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the `name` of your inputs so there error is likely on this line here:

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{box.id}}" name="<<Name of the widget here>>"/>
```

If that name is incorrect, the values won't be picked up by Django properly, this includes any formset prefixes.

However, an easier solution is to render the HTML as is, and then style it appropriately. For example, you can position the actual checkbox off screen and then use colors to high light what is checked and what isn't like so:

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
  color:red;
}
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label {
  color:blue;
}
```